# open pdf is in new tab

Tags: asp.net

I made pdf file in **iTextSharp** library. I use following code. this pdf is automatic save in file folder. but i want pdf is open is in new tab. How it is possible.

```
using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())

        {

            using (iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
            {
                using (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    doc.Open();
                    doc.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(lblMessage.Text.ToString()));
                    doc.Close();
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Receipt3.pdf");
                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider the [`<a>` target attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp). You can use this to open the PDF in a new Window, perhaps using something like:

```
<a href="GeneratePdf.ashx?somekey=10" target="_blank">
```

Update- as you have now said that you don't mind whether it is in a browser window or not, my preferred technique is to change the content disposition to attachment as per MercerTraieste answer.

If you are using ASP.NET, it is definitely a good idea to consider writing a custom HttpHandler to stream the PDF for you.